# Print unicode string in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a problem
When i run a .py file with (this file on my project pyramid)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
print "Hãy đợi đấy"
```

Result " Hãy đợi đấy "
That ok. But when i run project the result is:
" HÃ£y Ä‘á»£i Ä‘áº¥y " 
So my question is: what wrong.
I using Python 2.7
Window 7

@Ofir: 
I try it. And this is new bug

```
 print u"HÃ£y Ä‘á»£i Ä‘áº¥y"
  File "C:\env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark the string as unicode with a u:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
print u"Hãy đợi đấy"
```

Comment: I think there some file run first of all file on my project, so it dominate the rest

Comment: If you can't use UTF8 encoding in your files for some reasons, there are two possible approaches: either use a UTF8 external file and read it from your code, or escape the unicode characters in your string - see escaping in http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Answer (score 3):

So you need all these things:

- `coding: utf-8` at the top of file [✓]
- `u`-prefixed string literal [✓]
- Actually encode your file in UTF-8 [✘]

In your text editor, when you save the file, you need to select utf-8. This depends on your text editor.

Comment: All my file i was saved as UTF8. Only file development.ini i can't. Because when i run project have error   File "C:\env\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 9, in <module>
  

  File "C:\env\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 504, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: C:\env\advbus\development.ini, line: 1